# Windows 7 doesn't always recognize my nvidia geforce

Tags: windows-7, nvidia-geforce, display-driver

Weird behaviour I have on my Windows 7 machine with my GeForce GTX 260:

The card is recognized as standard vga adapter on every second boot. I usually have to unplug the card and restart the machine with my onboard chip. Then I have to log on to windows and shutdown the pc. Then I plug the geforce in again, boot the machine into windows, and then the card is recognized properly.

So my question is, how can I find out what's going wrong? Are there any logfiles I can view

By the way, I installed the latest geforce drivers, and reinstalled them several times

Comment: Have you disabled the onboard video chip in the BIOS?

Comment: Tried it, but it's not possible.

Comment: Maybe you should post your BIOS type (American Megatrends, Phoenix, etc.), version, and motherboard or computer manufacturer.

Comment: Sure, it's the "msi dka790gx platinum".

Forgot to mention that it all worked before a windows update, but I don't know which one ...

Comment: In your BIOS setup (press DEL during boot-up to get there) under Advanced BIOS Features there is a setting entitled Primary Graphic’s Adapter. From the screenshot I found it looks like you have settings of Internal and External. Try setting to something other than Internal.